# unsuccessful use of bc in float point math in shel

Tags: bash, bc

```
#!/bin/bash
    step=0.05
    short=0.05
    long=0.95
    for firstloop in {1..20}; do
        ratio=0.05
        for secondloop in {1..20} ; do
            echo $short $long $ratio >> file.txt
            time python3 main.py $short $long $ratio >> file.txt
            ratio= `echo $ratio + $step` | bc
        done
        short= `echo $short + $step`| bc
        long= `echo $long + $step`| bc

    done
```

when Iexecute the code this is what I get:

```
./script.sh: line 10: 0.05: command not found

real    0m25.329s
user    0m24.770s
sys 0m0.263s
./script.sh: line 10: 0.05: command not found

real    0m34.666s
user    0m32.319s
sys 0m0.623s
./script.sh: line 10: 0.05: command not found

real    0m31.425s
user    0m29.329s
sys 0m0.588s
./script.sh: line 10: 0.05: command not found
```

I have tried many variations so that I can increment the variables **short**, **long** and **ratio** with a float value. I know I can't deal with float points math in shell unless I use **bc**. I still haven't succeeded. what am I doing wrong?

After fixing the spaces errors and the format of bc as mentioned in the answer down below. I am left with this output:

```
real    0m0.871s
user    0m0.497s
sys 0m0.166s
++ echo '0 + 0.05'
++ bc
+ ratio=.05
+ for secondloop in '{1..20}'
+ echo 0 1 .05
+ python3 main.py 0 1 .05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 17, in main
    probability = [float(x) for x in sys.argv[:2]]
  File "main.py", line 17, in <listcomp>
    probability = [float(x) for x in sys.argv[:2]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'main.py'
```

this is basically what I get repeatedly while the values of the 3 variable change.

Comment: do not use spaces when doing any assignment `a=1` is correct and `a = 1` is not.

Comment: @PS. Thank you for your input.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with this code.

Comment: @pjh no issues detected with Spellcheck

Comment: It's [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), not "Spellcheck".  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) issues 14 warnings for the code as it is now.

Comment: yes I meant Shellcheck. it says that firstloop and secondloop are not used which is the case and it considers that as a bug, the problem I have is within the use of bc which Shellcheck says nothing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll make a style recommendation: use `$( )` instead of backticks. They're mostly equivalent, except they're easier to read and have slightly cleaner syntax (using escapes inside backticks or nesting backticks are ... odd). Also, it's generally a good idea to put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. use `python3 main.py "$short" "$long" "$ratio"` instead of `python3 main.py $short $long $ratio`).

Now, the real problems: first, you can't put spaces around the `=` in an assignment, or it'll be parsed as something completely different. In general, spaces are critical delimiters in shell syntax, and you shouldn't either add or remove them when copying examples.

Compare these commands:

```
ratio=0.05
ratio= 0.05
ratio = 0.05
```

The first does what it looks like -- sets the variable `ratio` to "0.05". The second is equivalent to `ratio='' 0.05` -- it tries to run "0.05" as a command, with the variable set to the empty string. This is what your script is doing, which is why you're getting the error "0.05: command not found". The third command tries to run "ratio" as a command, and pass it the arguments "=" and "0.05".

The second problem is that you have the pipe to `bc` outside the capture. Compare these commands:

```
ratio=$(echo "0.05 + 0.05" | bc)
ratio=$(echo "0.05 + 0.05") | bc
```

The first runs `echo "0.05 + 0.05" | bc` as a pipeline, and then captures the output and stores it in the variable `ratio`. This is what you want. The second sets `ratio` to "0.05 + 0.05" (the output of `echo "0.05 + 0.05"`), and then pipes the output of that (there isn't any) to `bc`. The output of `bc` (if there were any) would be printed to the Terminal rather than being captured.

In summary, you should replace every line like this:

```
ratio= `echo $ratio + $step` | bc
```

with something like this:

```
ratio=$(echo "$ratio + $step" | bc)
```

Comment: I added the modifications and now I have: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'main.py' " I thing the syntax with bc is still not correct!

Comment: In that case, it's important to know exactly what values are being passed. Put `set -x` before this section (and `set +x after it), and it'll print the equivalent of the commands it's executing as it runs.

Comment: the values are progressing logically. the execution of the main.py file though doesn't happen because it still considers them a string and therefore just returns the error: ValueError: could not convert a string to float: 'main.py' !!!!

Comment: Wait, it's trying to convert the string "main.py" to a float? There's something else wrong here -- either you're passing something else to the python script, or it's confused about how to get its arguments.

Comment: the idea is to run the file main.py several times with different inputs which are: **$ratio**, **$short** and **$long** that why the script is supposed to be handy! I don't understand where the string comes from because the variables in the script clearly are floats!

Comment: I realize that. But that error message indicates that something else has gone wrong -- it doesn't make sense based on what's in your question and my answer. Exactly what does it print (under `set -x`) when it gets to the `time python main.py ...` command that produces this error?

Comment: I have added the output to the question for clarity since in the comment it got all mashed up.

Comment: In the python script, `sys.argv` includes the program name as its first element. So if you run `python3 main.py 0 1 .05`, `sys.argv` will be `['main.py', '0', '1', '.05']` and `sys.argv[:2]` will be `['main.py', '0']`. You probably want `sys.argv[1:3]`.